# I have WWAN USB dongle. Can I hook it up into my network?

Tags: usb, wireless-router

Is there any way to connect a T-Mobile USB dongle to a wireless router so that I can broadcast the connection to my home?

If not directly to the router, how else could this be possible?

Comment: The thing you usually use for this is called a MiFi, by the way. _Extremely_ nifty.

Comment: digitxp: You don't really need one of those.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you relatively recent Centrino laptop, you can use [**Intel MyWiFi**](http://www.intel.com/products/wireless/mywifi.htm) to make it into an access point.  I've got it on my ThinkPad X200s, which is around 18 months old.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use Windows. You can create an AdHoc Network with Windows and share the Internet on this connection or use cables and a switch.

- Windows XP: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306126

I cant post more then one hyperlink, so just search "how-to-share-an-internet-connection-in-windows-7 dummies" on google, you'll find it for Windows 7